# How to set the background color of a DataGrid row in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a `DataGrid` object in my code behind and set the content with `obj.ItemsSource`.

Now I would like to set the background color of one specific row in the code behind. How can I achieve this?

**Update:**

I create the `DataGrid` object in the code behind like following:

```
var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = BuildDataGrid(); // Has at least one row
var row = (DataGridRow) dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
row.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

But the `row` object is `null`. Why is that?

Comment: creating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is strongly discouraged. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the `DataGridRow` using [**ItemContainerGenerator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of dataGrid.

In case you want to select row based on index value, use [**ContainerFromIndex()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ContainerFromIndex(0);
```

and in case want to get row based on item, use [**ContainerFromItem()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                    .ContainerFromItem(item);
```

Finally set background on row:

```
row.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Containers are not generated till dataGrid is not visible on GUI. You need to *wait for containers to be generated before you can set any property on DataGridRow*.

By container i meant DataGridRow in case of DataGrid. You need to modify your code like this:

```
var dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = BuildDataGrid();
dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
       if (dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == 
                           GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
       {
          var row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                               .ContainerFromIndex(0);
          row.Background = Brushes.Red;
       }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately my program crashes when I finally set the row color with row.Background = Brushes.Red. Everything else seems to work. Do you have a clue what I could have missed?

Comment: Post the crash exception message.

Comment: Are you getting the row? Isn't that null?

Comment: Okay, the row I am getting is null. See Update for details.

Comment: @John - I have updated my answer for the update you added in question. Now, see if that helps.

Comment: Perfect - thank you a lot. You really saved my day. If I get you right, the DataGridRow is generated after the first display of the DataGrid. With the event StatusChanged you first check if the containers are generated and if yes, set the color? When will the StatusChanged event happen? Doc only says, when the status is changed.

Comment: Yeah you got it right. DataGridRow gets generated once row gets loaded on UI. First status will be `GeneratingContainers` (initial) but once it gets loaded on UI, status changed to `ContainersGenerated` for all visible rows on UI.

Comment: @RohitVats I have problem with your solution. So if you can to help me: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310559/set-datagrid-row-background-color-wpf-loop)