# Change background colour of 'DataGrid' in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, row

I am trying to change in code behind the colour of a row of a `DataGrid` when a condition in that row occurs. Something like:

```
private void Datagrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{ 
    if((((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataContext)).Row.ItemArray[3].ToString()) == "ERROR")
        e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    else
        e.Row.Background = null;
}
```

That is very simple but it doesn't work:

1. I get an `InvalidCastException` on the `if` line.
2. Even if I put a single line with:

   `e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`

   ...it doesn't work and none of the lines turn red.

---ADD---

1 For the first problem the mistake comes from the following cast

```
(System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataContext))
```

where e comes from

```
private void Datagrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
```

so the event is correctly called but I can't get the row / column item to programmatically change the background or foreground.

2. I can't change the background but I can change the foreground. If you take a look at the following picture you will the that rows have alternate colours. I haven't set anything on purpouse nor there is anything particular in the datagrid definition in the xaml. But this is the reason why I can't set the background. How can I undo this condition?
   [image]

XAML -

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgEventsPCDmis" Grid.Row="6" FontSize="12" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10,21.4,9.6,0" LoadingRow="Datagrid_LoadingRow" AutoGeneratingColumn="Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="139" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" GridLinesVisibility="All"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

InvalidCastException  could be thrown because the DataContext might not have been set yet and hence it is null , or because the Row datacontext is not of the same type as that of System.Data.DataRowView. Simply put a breakpoint and check the value and type of e.Row.DataContext.

For setting the background of a DataGridRow then check:

[WPF Datagrid set selected row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row)

or

[How to set the background color of a DataGrid row in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206402/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-datagrid-row-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me..

```
e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red
```

and for invalidCast, I am quite certain that `e.Row.DataContext` is not DataRowView please debug and check what are you trying to cast.

Comment: <DataGrid x:Name="dtgEventsPCDmis" Grid.Row="6" FontSize="12" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="5" Margin="10,21.4,9.6,0" LoadingRow="Datagrid_LoadingRow" AutoGeneratingColumn="Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="139" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" GridLinesVisibility="All"/>

Comment: Background="{x:Null}"  ?? why ?

Comment: Because I don't want a background. I have a background gray gradient on my window and all controls are transparent as a background (see last attacched pic).

Comment: try background = transparent instead of null

Comment: No change still alternated colour rows